# How do we use textures in RGB565 format w/ iOS GLKTextureLoader?

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I am loading very large textures from JPG format, pre iOS5 I would use the Apple sample Texture2D class to convert the JPG texture to RGB565 format from RGB888 to halve the memory space needed. It would then get uploaded to the GPU w/glTexImage2D in RGB565 format.

With iOS5 I am converting calls to use the new GLKTextureLoader. However it seems like even though JPGs have no alpha channel, its just using RGB888 and therefore taking up twice the memory in GPU.

Is there a way to get GLKTextureLoader to use RGB565 when uploading to the GPU? I'm using [GLKTextureLoader textureWithContentsOfFile:jpgFile] right now. I also tried [GLKTextureLoader textureWithContentsOfData:data] and passing it an NSData of a raw RGB565 bitmap, but I get an error "{GLKTextureLoaderErrorKey=Image decoding failed}" when I try that.

Answer (score 7):

"textureWithContentsOfData" appears to be a broken method (note: the documentation is missing for it - there's no spec saying what it accepts) that Apple hasn't implemented yet - it fails for all the standard NSData inputs I tried.

I then took those and handed them direct to OpenGL using standard gl* method calls, and they worked fine, so the bug is in GLKit.

I've logged a support request with Apple requesting they explain their method, and document what it accepts. Until then, I strongly advise you to ignore the GLTextureInfo class (it's a nice idea, but it's so buggy it's not worth it - dropping this class gave me a 5x perofrmance improvement, instantly!)

---

UPDATE: response from Apple (paraphrasing) "hmm. we dont know either. please log it as a bug".

...and: response from Apple when receiving the bug: "this is not a bug, its as designed, we don't feel the need to document it. It's obvious what it does"

(their "obvious" was: you have to send it data that is in PNG or JPG or PVR *only* ... (and the PVR is only allowed if you're running on specific hardware) anything else will crash.)

Their final suggestion was: use the OpenGL texture calls to upload a texture, i.e. completely ignore GLKit when it comes to texture loading - because the OpenGL one works, is documented, etc. Disappointing, but seems to be true - and on live projects, the OpenGL texture calls are typically TEN TIMES FASTER than Apple's GLKit TextureInfo class. Seriously - don't use it, it's terrible :(.

Comment: Addendum: except: loading PVR textures is painful to do by hand (Imagination's own SDK is currently broken on iOS, and is incompatible with iOS anyway unless you force it into "legacypvr" mode). So, for PVR's ... GLTextureLoader is still by far the easiest way (although eventually you'll want to upgrade to using gl* methods and a custom PVR parser)